# Adjust UILabel to fit landscape and Portrait mode

Tags: ios, uilabel, landscape

I am trying to make a label which displays properly on both landscape and portrait mode.
The label looks fine when i am in portrait mode but when i switch to the landscape mode the label is not aligned correctly.Is there a way to adjust the UIlabel automatically when the screen is switched from one mode to another.

**Edit:**
This is the code that i have

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100 , 100, 100, 100)];
[label setText:@"xxx."];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
[self.view addSubview:label];
[label release];
```

I have also created a NStimer method which discards the label after 5 seconds

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by automatically, and how do you want it to be aligned?

You could add code to `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` to give the `UILabel` a new frame- but it's hard to post the exact code unless you're specific about what you want the label to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you mean shifting of your label.

You can use `autoresizingMask`. For example, for connecting label with left part of the screen:

```
yourLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

use autoresizingMask

```
lblBookmarkName.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```